# ASP.NET Binding DropDownList throwing error

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to bind an `asp:DropDownList` but I keep getting an error

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does
>   not contain a property with the name 'id_enabled'

Here is my `SqlDataSource`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="sql_enabled_ddl" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Tip-Tour %>"  

    SelectCommand ="SELECT 
                        id_enabled, 
                        description

                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            1 AS id_enabled,
                            'true' AS description

                         UNION 

                         SELECT 
                            2 AS id_enabled,
                            'false' AS description

                    ) AS passport_enabled">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and my DropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList
    ID="DropDownList2"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="sql_enabled_ddl"
    DataTextField="description"
    DataValueField="id_enabled"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("id_enabled") %>' 
    Width="87%">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to bind to **SelectedValue**, unless you use this inside data control like GridView.

Remove `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("id_enabled") %>'`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="sql_enabled_ddl"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Tip-Tour %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT 
                id_enabled, 
                description

            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    1 AS id_enabled,
                    'true' AS description

                    UNION 

                    SELECT 
                    2 AS id_enabled,
                    'false' AS description

            ) AS passport_enabled"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList
    ID="DropDownList2"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="sql_enabled_ddl"
    DataTextField="description"
    DataValueField="id_enabled"
    Width="87%">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: tthat throws a different error....Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'id_enabled'.

Comment: Could you test the above code in the new aspx page without master page?

Comment: this is inside a FormView EditItemTemplate

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'enabled', table 'sqlTipTour.dbo.tt_passport'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It is an another error which is different from the original question. It said you update to a column with NULL which doesn't allow null. Could you create a new question with the **update** code?

Comment: i posted the question again with all the code                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901786/asp-formview-edititemtemplate-binding-values